# How to resolve "Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__lcb_createopts_create referenced in function _main"

Tags: c++, c, couchbase

Keep getting "Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__lcb_createopts_create referenced in function _main" I see the function header in the couchbase.h file so not sure about why the issue is happening. Is it something to do with function call? Can someone please guide?

Comment: I'm guessing the couchbase SDK came with a `.lib` file you need to link against.